# Three.js loading .obj thats been converted from quads to triangles

Tags: 3d, three.js, blender

I used Blender to convert a model that was based on quads to all triangles.  The rendering of the object is now working perfectly.  However, the textures have gone away.  Do I have to do something to the jpg images associated with the .obj and .mtl files?

Comment: You dont need to do anything to the jpg but make sure that Blender created texture coordinates for all the triangles.

Comment: Um, how do I do that?  ;)  If if it did not how do I make sure it does?

Comment: Open the .obj file. Every line that starts with a 'v' defines a vertex. The ones that start with 'vn' define a vertex normal. And the ones that start with 'vt' define a vertex texture coordinate. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file for more info. As for Blender you will need to read the manual.